# Problem with adyen ecommerce demo Using JHipster and React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jhipster

I created a new project with the lastest JHipster version 6.10.5. I followed all previous steps of the demo without error. Now, when I copy/paste the content of checkout-status.tsx in my project, I get the following error.

```
TS2345: Argument of type '(props: { closeShoppingCart: (paymentType: any) => (dispatch: any) => Promise<any>; }) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<Matching<{ closeShoppingCart: (paymentType: any) => Promise<any>; }, { closeShoppingCart: (paymentType: any) => (dispatch: any) => Promise<any>; }>>'.
  Type '(props: { closeShoppingCart: (paymentType: any) => (dispatch: any) => Promise<any>; }) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<Matching<{ closeShoppingCart: (paymentType: any) => Promise<any>; }, { closeShoppingCart: (paymentType: any) => (dispatch: any) => Promise<any>; }>>'.
    Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
      Type 'PropsWithChildren<Matching<{ closeShoppingCart: (paymentType: any) => Promise<any>; }, { closeShoppingCart: (paymentType: any) => (dispatch: any) => Promise<any>; }>>' is not assignable to type '{ closeShoppingCart: (paymentType: any) => (dispatch: any) => Promise<any>; }'.
        The types returned by 'closeShoppingCart(...)' are incompatible between these types.
          Type 'Promise<any>' is not assignable to type '(dispatch: any) => Promise<any>'.
            Type 'Promise<any>' provides no match for the signature '(dispatch: any): Promise<any>'.
Version: typescript 3.8.3, eslint 6.8.0
Time: 33830 ms
```

I investigated this error but I did not find any solution. Please I need your help to continue with the other steps.
You can find the source code of the demo
[here](https://github.com/adyen-examples/adyen-java-react-ecommerce-example/commit/30899562564be5f2b6dd1291af812c3f4ff8e22e#r47064016).

Comment: I answered on GitHub for the same comment, adding it as an answer here as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [example](https://github.com/adyen-examples/adyen-java-react-ecommerce-example) uses JHipster v6.8.0 and that is the reason you are seeing the error as the newer version of TypeScript in the newer JHipster version is catching a signature issue that was missed by the older version used in the repo. I did reproduce the issue on the JHipster 6.10.5 and here is the solution

In `src/main/webapp/app/entities/shopping-cart/shopping-cart.reducer.ts` change the method signature of `const closeShoppingCart` to the below. Basically we are adding a better type declaration for the method here to make TypeScript happy

```js
export const closeShoppingCart: ICrudPutAction<string> = (paymentType: string) => async dispatch => {
  const result = await dispatch({
    type: ACTION_TYPES.UPDATE_SHOPPINGCART,
    payload: axios.put(`${apiUrl}/close/${paymentType}`)
  });
  return result;
};
```

Also in `src/main/webapp/app/modules/checkout/checkout-status.tsx`  for `const CheckoutStatus` you need to add type for `const { type } = useParams();`, just change to `const { type } = useParams<{type: string}>();`

**Note**: Btw you are copying from a particular commit but the repo itself have newer commits, especially for the parts you are copying, so make sure you didn't mix code from different commits, should not be an issue if you are following the [blog](https://dev.to/adyen/building-an-e-commerce-application-using-java-react-2iln). Once you are finished following the blog checkout the newer commits as there are some improvements

Comment: Please I got a new problem. When I create a route inside the module folder for managing my module components, the corresponding components never loaded. Please how to add a route in a module folder the same way it's done in the entity folder?

Comment: Difficult to say anything without seeing your code. Ideally you could follow the same steps as in entity or admin modules